# TempData value implicitly cast from List<string> to string[] after RedirectToAction()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using TempData to allow error message to be displayed after a redirect. For compatibility, I am using a `List<string>` to add messages into a list of errors in NotificationHelper class:

```
if (TempData["errorNotification"] == null) {
    TempData["errorNotification"] = new List<string> {
        message
    };
} else {
    var data = (List<string>) TempData["errorNotification"];
    data.Add(message);
    TempData["errorNotification"] = data;
}
```

Inside the controller, I fill that TempData with an error message and before the `return RedirectToAction()` call, TempData contains a dictionary record with `List<string>` (To be exact: `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``) as a value but right after the call, inside `Terms()` function, the value becomes an array (`System.String[]`).

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Terms()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    NotificationHelper.AddErrorNotification("error!", TempData);
    return RedirectToAction("Terms");
}
```

The issue is that in order to use the data, I am casting the type in the view like so:

`var errorMessages = TempData["errorNotification"] as List<string>;`

and after the conversion I have to do this instead:

`var errorMessages = TempData["errorNotification"] as string[];`

One of above casts will come back as null, because of expecting a wrong type (depending on if I try to render the view before or after the redirect). Is that a desired behavior of TempData? How can I make sure that the view can expect one specific type being provided?

Comment: You could always use `var errorMessages = TempData["errorNotification"] as IEnumerable<string>;` but you really shouldn't be using that code in a view anyway (you should be assigning it to a view model property (or `ViewBag` property) in the controller method

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the input. I assume that you mean the method returning the View, because from my understanding - that's how ViewBag works. The idea behind this notification though is that it will be displayed regardless of the redirect, so when I'm using AddErrorNotification method, I don't have to have information about which view is going to display it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up going with using `IEnumerable`, as @Stephen Muecke suggested since I was only looking for iterating over the data and not extending or changing it.

So in the view instead of trying to guess if it's a list or an array, I used `IEnumerable` to account for both:

```
var errorMessages = TempData["errorNotification"] as IEnumerable<string>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your list of strings before assigning it to the `TempData` if you want to persist the type, and then deserialize it on retrieval. That's what I ended up doing. Though in my case I ended up storing a list of `NotifyEntry` instead of a list of `string`.

```
public class NotifyEntry
{
    public NotifyType Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public enum NotifyType
{
    Success,
    Information,
    Warning,
    Error
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting work around. Do you know though, if it's the "correct" behavior or a bug that the lists are converted to arrays?

Thanks for the input - I decided to go with the IEnumerable in the view, where I read the TempData, because I am not going to change that data in any way.

Comment: Well the TempData is essentially just an collection of `KeyValuePair<string, object>`, so storing a full object is no issue. Though now that I think about my earlier decision, I'm trying to remember why I was preemptively serializing my value, and I can't remember the reason. I'll have to try storing it directly without serialization and see if anything pops up to remind me why I went that way... :-P